# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_oci'

Tags: php, oracle, dll, oracle-call-interface, instantclient

I have the following problem. When I execute a PHP command for example

```
php --version
```

I obtain the following:

```
**PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8_11g'** (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\oci8_11g (No se puede encontrar el m¾dulo especificado.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_oci8_11g.dll (%1 no es una aplicaci¾n Win32 vßlida.)) in Unknown on line 0

**Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8_11g'** (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\oci8_11g (No se puede encontrar el m¾dulo especificado.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_oci8_11g.dll (%1 no es una aplicaci¾n Win32 vßlida.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_oci' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\pdo_oci (No se puede encontrar el m¾dulo especificado.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_oci.dll (%1 no es una aplicaci¾n Win32 vßlida.)) in Unknown on line 0

**Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_oci'** (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\pdo_oci (No se puede encontrar el m¾dulo especificado.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_oci.dll (%1 no es una aplicaci¾n Win32 vßlida.)) in Unknown on line 0

PHP 7.3.2 (cli) (built: Feb  5 2019 22:55:35) ( ZTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x64 )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.2, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

And when I tried to use 'oci_connect' I obtain the following:

```
**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function oci_connect()** in C:\xampp\htdocs\enviar_correo_update\conexion.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\enviar_correo_update\conexion.php on line 3
```

My enviroment is the following:

- Windows Server 2016 Standard X64
- PHP 7.3.2

  - Compiler   MSVC15  (Visual C++ 2017)
  - Architecture       x64
  - Thread Safety  enabled
- Oracle DB 11g (11.2 X86)
- instantclient_11_2 (x86)

  - Route C:\instantclient_11_2
- I download the php_oci8-2.2.0-7.3-ts-vc15-x64 DLL package 
  ( https://pecl.php.net/package/oci8/2.2.0/windows ) and paste it in
  C:\xampp\php\ext
- My variables **PATH and TNS_ADMIN** have the location of instantclient (C:\instantclient_11_2)
- My PHP.ini has uncommented the extensions that i need:

----PHP.INI---

```
extension=mysqli

extension=oci8_11g

;extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client

;extension=odbc

;extension=openssl

;extension=pdo_firebird

extension=pdo_mysql

extension=pdo_oci

;extension=pdo_odbc
```

If I run where oci*:

```
C:\Users\fpoveda.gprosoft>where oci*
C:\instantclient_11_2\oci.dll
C:\instantclient_11_2\oci.sym
C:\instantclient_11_2\ocijdbc11.dll
C:\instantclient_11_2\ocijdbc11.sym
C:\instantclient_11_2\ociw32.dll
C:\instantclient_11_2\ociw32.sym
C:\orant\BIN\OCI.DLL
C:\orant\BIN\OCIW32.DLL
```

I don't know where is the problem. I spent more than two days in that and nothing. If someone can help me i will be veary grateful.

Thanks

Comment: Review the installation instructions at https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/installing-xampp-for-php-and-oracle-database  Note how it shows to determine whether you need 32 or 64 bit Oracle client libraries.  You then need to set your PATH to these libraries.  Generally you don't need both XE and Instant Client unless you need a different version number or different architecture.